# I want to query the resource Massambala in the following jena model. How should I do it

Tags: rdf, jena

I am using Apache Jena and I would like to query specific resources from my RDF data. Now Given the below RDF document, I would like to query the resource Massambala and save it into a file.

So basically the ontology and the resource should be saved into the file

how should I go about it?

Thank you in  advance

The following is the model I am working on

```
    <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:dados="http://localhost:8080/dados/#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Fruteiras">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Horticulas">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Cereais">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Raizes">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#LeguminosasEoleaginosas">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#areaColhida">
    <rdfs:range>
      <xsd:double rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#hectares">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
      </xsd:double>
    </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#ano">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#producao">
    <rdfs:range>
      <xsd:double rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#toneladas">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
      </xsd:double>
    </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#areaSemeada">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#hectares"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#produtividade">
    <rdfs:range>
      <xsd:double rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#kilogramasPorHectares">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
      </xsd:double>
    </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Producto"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <dados:Cereais rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Massambala">
    <dados:ano>2017/2018</dados:ano>
    <dados:produtividade>296</dados:produtividade>
    <dados:producao>39363</dados:producao>
    <dados:areaColhida>133148</dados:areaColhida>
    <dados:areaSemeada>145161</dados:areaSemeada>
  </dados:Cereais>

  <dados:Raizes rdf:about="http://localhost:8080/dados/#Batata_doce">
    <dados:ano>2017/2018</dados:ano>
    <dados:produtividade>9663</dados:produtividade>
    <dados:producao>1545326</dados:producao>
    <dados:areaColhida>159922</dados:areaColhida>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/page/Sweet_potato"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Batata-doce"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batata-doce"/>
    <dados:areaSemeada>165319</dados:areaSemeada>
  </dados:Raizes>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: use SPARQL or the RDF API of Jena? Also, what is the result of your "query"? If you want RDF, write a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query. If you want to use the Jena RDF API directly, read the docs https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Statements

Comment: I am using the RDF API of Jena and I am trying to create a CONSTRUCT but seems too dificult for me.  I just can't get it right

Comment: that's why I told you to use the RDF API of Jena instead of the SPARQL layer ... use `model.listStatements()` with your resource as first argument and then create a new model from those statements and write the new model to disk. done